# Angular material child mat-card not responsive

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have a simple situation with a mat-card element occupying the entire page in which I put a background color gradient and some header text. I include a 'child' mat-card element containing a list, and underneath that, a button.

The html code looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.component.css">
<mat-card class="main_body">

  <mat-card-header class="matheader1">
    <h1>LNI Provisioning Application</h1>
  </mat-card-header>

  <mat-card class="matcard1">
    <mat-list >
      <mat-list-item>Browser: {{deviceInfo.browser}}</mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item>Browser version: {{deviceInfo.browser_version}}</mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item>Device: {{deviceInfo.device}}</mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item>Device type: {{deviceInfo.deviceType}}</mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item>OS: {{deviceInfo.os}}</mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item>OS Version: {{deviceInfo.os_version}}</mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item>orientation: {{deviceInfo.orientation}}</mat-list-item>
      <mat-list-item>userAgent: {{deviceInfo.userAgent}}</mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>
  </mat-card>


  <mat-card-header class="matheader1">
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="checkEthernet()">Check for Connectivity</button>
  </mat-card-header>

</mat-card>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The css file app.component.css looks like this:

```
.main_body{
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(218, 218, 253),  rgb(246, 253, 225));
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: clamp(.25rem, 5vw, 2rem);
  width:100%;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: top-center;
  align-items: center; /* This aligns the cards on the page*/
}

.matcard1{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width:auto;
  justify-content: top-center;
  font-size: clamp(.25rem, 5vw, 1rem);
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.matheader1{
  padding: 0px;
}
```

On a full page, the screen looks as I want. However, as I decrease the horizontal size the background mat-card, the header, and the button all shrink as they should. The child mat-card with the list remains fixed in size.

I am using FlexBox because the flex-layout is deprecated and to be killed later this year (as I understand it). I have tried all kinds of combinations of css settings at the mat-card, mat-list, and mat-list-item levels for that middle element and they are all ignored (except the margin-bottom entry). The biggest problem, however, is that I cannot get that card-encapsulated list and card to shrink like the remaining elements.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you publish a reproduction of this issue to stackblitz or something similar?

Comment: It will be a learning curve but its something I should learn to do. I did take out the nested mat-card and created my own 'card' and used <p> instead of mat-list and it all worked. I could not find a case of nested mat-cards so maybe that is the issue.

Comment: @Martin Complete failure in stackblitz. A whole slew of problems on a project that runs locally. Became a dead stop after it tried to install a dependency @* while building. Have no idea where it got that from. Submitted a bug.